# Laravel : Display the data in a table

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5.1

I have a form this form is for the employees and each employee have a payment for each year,the admin should fill the data and save it, also the previous data should be filled on the right place on the form otherwise if there is no data the input field should be empty, here is what should data look like :

[image]

but what I get is this:
[image]

**MY CODE :**
**Controller**

```
$years = Year::with('employeeData')->get();

    $indicators = Indicator::all();
 return view('sustainability-data.input-data', compact('years', 'indicators'));
```

**View**

```
@foreach($employees as $index=>$employee)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$employee->name}}</td>
                        @foreach($years as $year)
                            <td>
                                @foreach($year->employeeData as $datum)
                                        @if($datum->employee_id == $employee->id)
                                            {!! Form::text('row[$index][value]' ,$datum->value,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                        @endif

                                @endforeach
                            </td>
                        @endforeach
```

anyone have an idea how to solve this before I lose my mind , I tried many ways but I failed to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the structure of `@foreach($year->employeeData as $datum)`. I'm assuming that if an employee doesn't already have data for a given year then `@if($datum->employee_id == $employee->id)` will never evaluate to `true`. If this is the case then then the code that outputs the form field won't run.

The simplest way of converting what you currently have is to replace the `@foreach` with something like the following:

```
@if($year->emplyeeData()->where('employee_id', $employee->id)->count())
    {!! Form::text('row[$index][value]', $year->emplyeeData()->where('employee_id', $employee->id)->get()->value, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
@else
    {!! Form::text('row[$index][value]', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
@endif
```

Please note, I've made a few guesses of how your  models are set up so this code may need to be adapted.

I would also consider removing this logic from the view and maybe adding a method to your `Employee` model called `getDataForYear` which returns the value or an empty string.

Comment: Many Thanks, I am really appreciate your help :D

Comment: No problem. I've also just noticed that `'row[$index][value]'` needs to be in double quotation marks. The current version wouldn't replace `$index` with its value.

Comment: Yes you are right I notice that too, Thank you so much :D